# How to create different the authentication error message in Symfony 5.4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5

By default, it shows error "Invalid credentials.". I've already seen answers like "Go to translations, create *security.en.yaml* and type this:

```
# translations/security.en.yaml
'Invalid credentials.': 'Invalid email or password'
```

But how to create different errors? For example, "Invalid password" when password is wrong and "Email does not exists" when email is wrong. How to do it?

Comment: It's considered bad practice (and possibly a law-violating one, considering GDPR), giving information about "this account exists/does not exist on this service". What you are trying to do is a bad idea, and you shouldn't go into that direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you must create custom authorization and exceptions.

example:
**config/packages/security.yaml**

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    ...
    providers: 
    ...
    firewalls:
        ...
        client:
            pattern: ^/
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\ClientLoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: store.account.logout
                target: store.home
    access_control:
        ...
```

**src/Security/ClientLoginFormAuthenticator.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Security;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Security\Exception\CustomException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use function in_array;

class ClientLoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    private const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'store.account.login';

    public function __construct(private UserRepository $userRepository, private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {}

    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $password = $request->request->get('_password');
        $username = $request->request->get('_username');
        $csrfToken = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($username, function ($userIdentifier) {
                $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $userIdentifier]);
                if ($user && in_array('ROLE_CLIENT', $user->getRoles(), true)) {
                    return $user;
                }

                //next condition
                if($user && $user->getEmail() === 'superadmin@example.com') {
                    throw new CustomException();
                }

                throw new BadCredentialsException(); //default exception
            }),
            new PasswordCredentials($password),
            [new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $csrfToken)]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

**src/Security/Exception/CustomException.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Security\Exception;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class CustomException extends AuthenticationException
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getMessageKey()
    {
        return 'My Message.';
    }
}
```

It works for me! :) Good luck!